# Continuity of a linear functional $T$: $\ker{T}$ is closed

Tags: functional-analysis

I was solving this exercise:

> let $T: C^{0}([0,b]) \rightarrow  C^{0}([0,b])$ s.t. $u \mapsto \int_{0}^{t}e^{t-x}u(x)dx$.
>   Prove $T$ is continuous.

Of course $T$ is linear. It's continuous since this functional is bounded (and I have no problem in showing it)

Then, from theory I know that $\ker{T}$ must be a closed set: I'd like to show it.

---

Let $u(x) \in C^{0}([0,b])$ s.t. $T(u)=0$.

This amounts to 
$\int_{0}^{t} e^{t-x} u(x)dx=0$, which implies $u(x)=0, \forall x \in C^{0}([0,b])$, since $t$ is finite and $e^{t-x} \ne0$

Then $\ker{T}=\{u: u(x)=0\}$. *Intuitively*, this set is closed since it contains all its accumulation points. Is this a correct way to say it's closed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That set is closed because $T$ is continuous, $\{0\}$ is closed, and $\ker T=T^{-1}\bigl(\{0\}\bigr)$

Comment: That was my first guess, then I thought thay the elements of the kernel are functions, and this confused me a little